# Typescript: How I can define strictly constant from type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, constants

I tried to define a type and create a constant from this type. This is what I did:

```
type  StatusType = 'active' | 'pending';

type Status = Record<Uppercase<StatusType>, Capitalize<StatusType>>;

const UserStatus: Status = {
    ACTIVE: 'Active',
    PENDING: 'Pending'
}
```

but this also fine if I do something like:

```
const UserStatus: Status = {
    ACTIVE: 'Active',
    PENDING: 'Active'
}
```

Is there any way to prevent this? I want the value of the **PENDING** key to be  must be **Pending**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
type StatusType = 'active' | 'pending';


type Status = {
    [P in StatusType as Uppercase<P>]: Capitalize<P>
}

const UserStatus: Status = {
    ACTIVE: 'Active',
    PENDING: 'Pending'
}

const UserStatus2: Status = {
    ACTIVE: 'Active',
    PENDING: 'Active' // expected error
}
```

You should use mapped type instead

Comment: Awesome! you save my life bro

Comment: @DFM No problem)) IF it helpful please dont forget to accept it, it will help other people